# 'http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release' no longer has a Release file (apt update error on ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: apt, updates, 21.04

On a Ubuntu 21.04 the `sudo apt update` command generates console ouput as follows:

```console
barium@berta$ sudo apt update
...
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease                                
Err:4 http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:6c::644 80]
...
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stable/updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Manual changes to the Ubuntu Software & Updates Manager produce the same error message.

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains among others the following deb statements:

```console
barium@berta$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
...
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
...
```

In an answer to a similar post it was suggested to replace 'archive.ubuntu.com' and 'security.ubuntu.com' with 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'. That didn't work.

Comment: Is the use of Debian sources on your system intentional?

Comment: Normal Ubuntu installations do not have Debian Security repositories. Try removing the lines with `security.debian.org` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as files in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that refers to Debian.

Comment: Your system is likely not a Ubuntu one; as the post you provided applies on with a Debian install.  If it was added to a Ubuntu install; you may no longer be using Ubuntu as `apt` & `dpkg` cannot tell which packages are foreign or local - they upgrade to the latest available in the sources.  It looks to me that you're using a Debian system & not a Ubuntu one.  `ubuntu-security-status` may provide some clues but I'd explore what you were running, and what you're now running as it may be neither - a *frakensystem* with bits of both & no longer either Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: So far I assumed the debian packages were called implicitly by the ubuntu one's. According to your answers that shouldn't be the case so I checked the sources.list file again, but found no line containing a debain package. 

Might there be multiple sources.list files and if so where or how will I find them? In sources.list.d and elsewhere?

Comment: Furthermore If I make changes to these files, removing the debian repos, is there any danger of corrupting the system?

Comment: The machine I am working on is an Ubuntu system, but some automatization magic run on it, in order to setup many different tools that I (obviously) don't comprehend.